# Ruby Gem path is incorrect due to accent in user folder name in Windows. How to fix it?

Tags: ruby, windows-7, path, rubygems

I have Ruby installed on my work PC **1.9.3 version** and **Gem 1.8.24** but when I try to install Rails I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory - C:/Users/B"k"nyi Szabolcs
```

**Can I fix this without creating a new Windows User?**

*Thanks for the help in advance.*

My Windows user folder name is : Bökönyi Szabolcs

gem env says:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I figured it out and the only problem was with the accent so instead of `SET HOME %USERPROFILE%` I used `SET HOME="C:/Users/Bökönyi Szabolcs"` and now the `gem install rails` works.